# Why can't the exported cURLS be imported back to POSTMAN?

Tags: http, postman

The latest update of the POSTMAN (7.16) doesn't seem to understand the cURL when importing them.

Here is a cURL exported by POSTMAN itself via the "Code" option.

```
curl -L -X POST 'https://example.com/example/' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "requestFields":{
        "address":"123, Main Street",
        "ping":false
    }
}'
```

But when this cURLis is tried to be imported to POSTMAN again, it doesn't populate the Body area of the request.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: You can manually remove the `-raw` part of `--data-raw` and it should import correctly. Not a great workaround though.

Comment: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/7895